tikczd: how move label on one arrow
In the triangular diagram shown, produced from the code below using the tikz-cd package, how can I move the $\cong$ label upwards (and, necessarily, somewhat to the right, so that it is at the same vertical height as the label $f^{\ast}$?
  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \begin{document}
  
  \tikzset{close/.style={outer sep=-3pt}}
  
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
    X \arrow[swap]{d}{q}\arrow{r}{f} & Y
    \\
    X/\sim \arrow[dashed,close]{ur}{f^{\ast}}\arrow[swap,dashed]{ur}{\cong} & 
  \end{tikzcd}
  
  \end{document}



\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{close/.style={outer sep=-3pt}}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large, column sep=large]
X \arrow[swap]{d}{q}\arrow{r}{f} & Y
\\
X/\sim \arrow[dashed, close]{ur}{f^{\ast}}[xshift=14pt]{\cong} & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}



You can set the style for the single label if you use the “modern” syntax.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  close/.style={outer sep=#1},
  close/.default=-3pt,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
  X \arrow[d,"q"'] \arrow[r,"f"] & Y
  \\
  X/{\sim} \arrow[ur,dashed,"f^{\ast}" close,"\cong"' near end]
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
  X \arrow[d,"q"'] \arrow[r,"f"] & Y
  \\
  X/{\sim} \arrow[ur,dashed,"f^{\ast}" close,"\cong"' {pos=0.75}]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}

In the particular case, near end is sufficient, but I add a different version that could be useful in other situations.
The close style has been modified so you can tailor it to other cases by passing it the desired dimension.

Note X/{\sim}, where the braces avoid the wrong spacing in front of the symbol.

In my "real" document, I actuallyused X/\mathord{\sim}, which I think accomplishes the same spacing fix.

@murray Yes, indeed. Just the braces is the same.

You can make both labels as a single unit using a marking label, but you must set sloped=false and use \scriptstyle. The space between the symbols can be adjusted by changing the kern value.

  \documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \begin{document}
  
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=large]
    X \arrow[swap]{d}{q}\arrow{r}{f} & Y\\
    X/{\sim} \arrow[dashed, ur, "\scriptstyle f^{\ast}\kern.7em\cong"{marking, sloped=false}] & 
  \end{tikzcd}
  
  \end{document}


If you just use anchor=center instead of marking (which it also does), you don't have to undo all its other changes.
